# Query individual field after group by

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a relation

```
A = 
(John,19,SF)
(Mary,20,NY)
(Bill,23,SF)
(Joe,25,SF)
```

The schema is (name, age, city)

```
B = foreach (group A by city) 
{
   sorted = ORDER A BY age;
   info = LIMIT sorted 10;
   GENERATE group, info.name;
}
```

Pig complains that "Scalar has more than one row in the output" for GENERATE group, info.name;

How to query individual field in the bag after group by?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me the above code is working and the output for 'Dump B;' is

(NY,{(Mary)})
(SF,{(John),(Bill),(Joe)})

As far as querying individual field after group by is concerned, you will have to refer in the same way you are doing now, Alias.fieldName.